# How to fix 'Uncaught (in promise)' error in primeNG calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm setting up primeNG calendar, and want to know how to display saved date while editing.[image]

```
<p-calendar name="startDate" [(ngModel)]="classPrg.startDate"> </p-calendar> 
<p-calendar name="endDate" [(ngModel)]="classPrg.endDate"></p-calendar>
```

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.classPrg = this.classPrgStore.state.entry.data; 
    if (!this.classPrg) { 
        let id: string = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['id']; 
        if (await this.classPrgStore.loadClassPrg(id).toPromise()) { 
            this.classPrg = this.classPrgStore.state.entry.data; 
            this.classPrg.startDate = new Date(this.classPrg.startDate); 
            this.classPrg.endDate = new Date(this.classPrg.endDate); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code, where you made the promise.

Comment: <p-calendar name="startDate" [(ngModel)]="classPrg.startDate"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar name="endDate" [(ngModel)]="classPrg.endDate"></p-calendar>
async ngOnInit() {
    this.classPrg = this.classPrgStore.state.entry.data;
    if (!this.classPrg) {
      let id: string = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
      if (await this.classPrgStore.loadClassPrg(id).toPromise()) {
        this.classPrg = this.classPrgStore.state.entry.data;
        this.classPrg.startDate = new Date(this.classPrg.startDate);
        this.classPrg.endDate = new Date(this.classPrg.endDate);
      }}}

Answer (score 0):

This error is warning you that an error happened in a promise but there was no handler.

Since you're using `async/await` with your promise, you need a `catch` block:

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.classPrg = this.classPrgStore.state.entry.data; 
    if (!this.classPrg) { 
        let id: string = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params['id']; 
        try {
            if (await this.classPrgStore.loadClassPrg(id).toPromise()) { 
                this.classPrg = this.classPrgStore.state.entry.data; 
                this.classPrg.startDate = new Date(this.classPrg.startDate); 
                this.classPrg.endDate = new Date(this.classPrg.endDate); 
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle error, or just leave blank to ignore error
        }
    }
}
```